# += Operator Chaining (with a dash of UB)

Tags: c, pointers, chaining, undefined-behavior

I understand there is no sequence point here before the semicolon, but is there a plausible explanation for the dereferenced pointer to use the old value 2 in the expression?

Or can it be simply put down as undefined behaviour?

```
int i=2;
int *x=&i;
*x+=*x+=i+=7;
```

Result:

```
i= 13
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is "simply" undefined behavior.

That said, the compiler probably emits code that reads the value of `i` once then performs all the arithmetic, then stores the new value of `i`.

The obvious way to find out the real explanation would be to go look at the assembly generated by the compiler.

Answer (score -3):

The behaviour isn't undefined, it is down to the way the compiler breaks down the expression and pushes the intermediate results onto the stack.  The two `*x`s are calculated first (both equal 2) and are pushed onto the stack.  Then `i` has 7 added to it and equals 9. Then the second `*x`, which still equals 2, is pulled off the stack, and added, to make 11.  Then the first `*x` is pulled off the stack and added to the 11 to make 13.

Look up Reverse Polish Notation for hints on what is going on here.

Comment: It is most definitely undefined behavior, and has nothing to do with stacks.

Comment: AFAIK, if some expression changes some variable more than once, it's UB. If x didn't point to i, that would be a different story. Maybe.

Comment: @eq, @Sergey, I think you might misunderstand how the compiler breaks down that line.  It doesn't evaluate it left-to-right, it breaks it down according to precedence rules, and stores intermediate results.  My description of what is going on is correct.  An expression can change a variable more than once, but if you understand and follow the precedence rules and know how compilers work, then the result of the expression is not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Kernow: No, you seem to misunderstand the programming language "C", which is defined per C standard (latest version "ISO/IEC 9899:1999"). *In this case* "Undefined behavior" is a result of an operation the standard did not explicitly define. One such example is modifying a variable multiple times with no sequence points in between. A conforming C compiler might produce a program that gives no value at all - or simply crashes; the programming language "C" will give you no more insight to that.

Comment: Precedence rules do not define the actual order of operations in cases like this.

Comment: 6.5/2: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression." `*x+=*x+=i+= 7;` most definitely violates that restriction, since the value stored at `i` is being modified multiple times.  Behavior is undefined.  *Any* result is allowed.